# Pandas fillna based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, nan

I'm still new to pandas, but I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
    d_title    d_prefix                            d_header d_country d_subtitles  d_season  d_episode
0        NaN        NaN                 ##### MOROCCO #####   Morocco         NaN       NaN        NaN
1     title1         AR                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
2     title2         AR                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
3        NaN        NaN               ##### MOROCCO 2 #####   Morocco         NaN       NaN        NaN
4     title3         AR                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
5        NaN        NaN                 ##### ALGERIA #####   Algeria         NaN       NaN        NaN
6     title4         AR                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
7     title5         AR                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
8     title6         IT                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
9     title7         PL                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       1.0        1.0
10    title8         UK                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
11    title9         UK                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
```

and I'm trying to fill all NaN fields in the 'd_header' column using the following conditions:

- 'd_header' column should be set only for rows belonging to the same group
- the group should be determined by the 'd_prefix' column value of a row immediately after non-Nan 'd_header' row

So in the following example:

- 0: 'd_header' == '##### MOROCCO #####'
- 1: check 'd_prefix' and set 'd_header' column for all rows going forward to '##### MOROCCO #####' until 'd_prefix' has changed (set value to NaN) OR new 'd_header' found (start over)

```
    d_title    d_prefix                            d_header d_country d_subtitles  d_season  d_episode
0        NaN        NaN                 ##### MOROCCO #####   Morocco         NaN       NaN        NaN
1     title1         AR                 ##### MOROCCO #####       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
2     title2         AR                 ##### MOROCCO #####       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
3        NaN        NaN             ##### MOROCCO TNT #####   Morocco         NaN       NaN        NaN
4     title3         AR             ##### MOROCCO TNT #####       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
5        NaN        NaN                 ##### ALGERIA #####   Algeria         NaN       NaN        NaN
6     title4         AR                 ##### ALGERIA #####       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
7     title5         AR                 ##### ALGERIA #####       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
8     title6         IT                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
9     title7         PL                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       1.0        1.0
10    title8         UK                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
11    title9         UK                                 NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN        NaN
```

but I'm not having any luck with this approach. Would there be a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: This may be a duplicate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111425/cannot-use-fillna-when-a-condition-is-introduced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **d_prefix** is almost the grouping key you need. `bfill` it then `groupby()`
- reduced to simple `ffill`

```
df = df.assign(d_header=df.assign(t_prefix=df.d_prefix.fillna(method="bfill"))
 .groupby("t_prefix", as_index=False).apply(lambda dfa: dfa.d_header.fillna(method="ffill"))
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

|  | d_title | d_prefix | d_header | d_country | d_subtitles | d_season | d_episode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | nan | ##### MOROCCO ##### | Morocco | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | title1 | AR | ##### MOROCCO ##### | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | title2 | AR | ##### MOROCCO ##### | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | nan | nan | ##### MOROCCO 2 ##### | Morocco | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | title3 | AR | ##### MOROCCO 2 ##### | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 5 | nan | nan | ##### ALGERIA ##### | Algeria | nan | nan | nan |
| 6 | title4 | AR | ##### ALGERIA ##### | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 7 | title5 | AR | ##### ALGERIA ##### | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 8 | title6 | IT | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 9 | title7 | PL | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | title8 | UK | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 11 | title9 | UK | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Rob