# Replace NaN values in dataframe with corresponding value based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with music genres and genres codes. Now some of these genres are NaN's values but do have genres codes. Based on this genre code, I want to look up the genre in the data frame and replace the NaN value with the corresponding genre.

E.g.

Row 1:
genre = NaN
genre_code = 1

Row 2:
genre = Rock
genre_code = 1

The struggle I am having is, how to make this dynamic. I can do this hardcoded like this:

```
def findReplaceGenre():
for genre, row in dataframe_combined["genres"].iteritems():
    if (pd.isna(row)):
        dataframe_combined.loc[dataframe_combined["genres_code"] == "1", "genres"] = "Rock"
    else:
        continue

findReplaceGenre()
```

Which makes all genres_codes that have the label 1 genre *Rock* if the genre is NaN.

Now, the dataset contains hundreds of genres and rows with NaNs values. Is there a way to make this dynamic, so that the function looks up the genre code, finds the same genre_code that has a genre, and then replaces the NaN value. Thus, far I have:

```
def findReplaceGenre():
for genre, row in dataframe_combined["genres"].iteritems():
    if (pd.isna(row)):
        dataframe_combined.loc[dataframe_combined["genres_code"] == dataframe_combined["genres_code"], "genres"] = dataframe_combined["genres"].loc[~dataframe_combined["genres"].isna()].iloc[0]
    else:
        continue

findReplaceGenre()
```

Where I want to check that the genre_codes are the same and then find the first non-NaN value in the genre. My reasoning is that iterating over the rows, I would assume it checks at row level. However, it keeps giving the first non-NaN genre result for all the NaN's.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share some sample data

Comment: looks same as question I've already answered today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492618/pandas-fillna-based-on-a-condition/66495143#66495143

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).